# BCP syntax to create CSV file

Tags: sql-server, bcp

When I try to run this procedure, it just give gives me the switches available to BCP. This is my first time with BCP. I'm trying to write a stored procedure to export one day of data to a CSV.

```
declare @startdate as datetime = '2017-01-24'
declare @enddate as datetime = dateadd(day,1,@startdate)

declare @sql varchar(8000)

set @sql =
'bcp "select * from tblBOJEOJ
where system = ''MKEV03''
and [date] between ''' + cast(@startdate as nvarchar(11)) + ''' and ''' + cast(@enddate as nvarchar(11)) + ''' " 
queryout D:\Temp\Galaxy\BOJEOJ_.csv
-c -t, -T -S ' + @@SERVERNAME 

print @sql

exec master..xp_cmdshell @sql
```

This is what returns[image: Return]

Thanks

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (That code is product specific.)

Comment: Can you include the result from your PRINT statement in the question?

Comment: The single line BCP below fixed it.

Answer (score 1):

`BCP` is quite strange. Keep the `BCP` command in single line

```
declare @sql varchar(8000)

set @sql =
'bcp "select * from tblBOJEOJ where system = ''MKEV03'' and [date] between ''' + cast(@startdate as nvarchar(11)) + ''' and ''' + cast(@enddate as nvarchar(11)) + ''' " queryout D:\Temp\Galaxy\BOJEOJ_.csv -c -t, -T -S ' + @@SERVERNAME 

print @sql

exec master..xp_cmdshell @sql
```

Comment: Thanks this fixed it!  I did have to add dbname.dbo to my table in the select.

Comment: @jwhitf4770 - Instead you can use `-d` parameter

Comment: Is there a switch to put column names on the file?